# Django: passing form input to the url

Tags: django

In django, I'm having problems passing the number that was inputed into a form to an URL:

I try like this:
templates->index.html

```
<form action="/mysite/{{ number }}/details.html" method="post">
<p><label for="number">Give me a number:</label>    
    <input type="text" name="number" id="number" /></p> <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

but the result is **/mysite//details.html**, instead of **/mysite/123/details.html** (when the user inputs 123 in the requested form)

Can you please give me an advise?

Thanks,

JJ

Comment: Paste your views.py here

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be configuring your action url in this manner. And the user POST-ed number 123 is passed in to your view function as `request.POST['number']` without you specifying it in the action url.

Your action url can simply be `{% url 'send_details' %}` corresponding to a url definition that is

```
    url(r'^mysite/details/$',
    'send_details',
    name='send_details'),
```

And your `send_details` view function will receive `request.POST['number']` when the user submits it.

There's no necessity to have the number in your template as a context variable.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did it as you suggested.   (my initial desire was to have the number in the URL - so that users could go directly to  that page by URL, instead of going through the form).

Comment: hmm. not sure why you would have needed that. the purpose of the form is to collect user input.  if you do need to redirect the user to a specific result page (with a specific url) after that, you can always use `HttpResponseRedirect` and `reverse` in your view function (upon successfully processing the form) to send the user to that specific url.